# Why doesn't my service start after installation?

Tags: c#, .net, service, windows-services, installation

I've created a windows service, which is set to start automatically. I also added following code to installer:

```
    public ProjectInstaller()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        serviceProcessInstaller1.AfterInstall += new InstallEventHandler(serviceProcessInstaller1_AfterInstall); 
    }

    void serviceProcessInstaller1_AfterInstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var sc = new ServiceController(serviceInstaller1.ServiceName);
            sc.Start();
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }

    protected override void OnCommitted(IDictionary savedState)
    {
        try
        {
            var sc = new ServiceController(serviceInstaller1.ServiceName);
            sc.Start();
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

The service is installed properly, but it never starts.

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: I have had similar problems in the past because I had the service control manager (SCM) console open while un/installing a service. Make sure your SCM is closed?

Comment: I've closed the console and repeated installation process, without any luck

Comment: check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247815/automatically-start-windows-service-on-install

Comment: Services have Access Control List, which means that you can control who can start or stop a service. Are you sure that the user you are running the install under has permission to actaully start the service?

Comment: @user957902: yes, the installation program runs with administrative rights.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need to put in some temporary diagnostic logging, maybe using `System.IO.File.WriteAllText();`. I know it's not the answer you're looking for, but it'll probably give you the quickest solution!

```
try
{
    var sc = new ServiceController(serviceInstaller1.ServiceName);
    sc.Start();
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"c:\temp\servicestart.txt", "Service started");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"c:\temp\servicestart.txt", ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure in your `Main()` function that you have this line:

`ServiceBase.Run(new ServiceClass());`

I've been guilty a few times of leaving 
`Application.Run(new Class());` 
(If you started off of a windows form app)

Comment: After I install the service, I can start it manually. It just doesn't happen automatically. The way I see this code, it's concerned with the service startup process

Comment: oh ok, I wasn't aware you could start it manually. I just thought it wasn't able to start in general

Answer (score 0):

I've created a service a while ago and what mine differs from yours is that you declared this way

`var sc = new ServiceController(serviceInstaller1.ServiceName);`

mine instead of taking the serviceInstaller1.ServiceName I was giving the name via a simple string like this

`var sc = new ServiceController("MyService");`

I think this isn't the problem at all, but when talking about services everything is worth a try

EDIT:
giving a look at it now I've seen that the name I used was actually the DisplayName not the service name, try passing it manually or by using `serviceInstaller1.DisplayName`

Comment: I've tried this in several permutations already. Entering service name with text was one of those. Regretfully, with no effect

Comment: Have you tried the one I've said with DisplayName instead of ServiceName? In my service the DisplayName was "Sincronização" while ServiceName was "Sincronização Pedido Produto" the latter didn't worked for me

Comment: One thing: the propertie StartType of the serviceInstaller1 is set to Automatic?

Comment: yes, its automatic; and in my case, both display name and service name are the same

Answer (score 0):

Does it possibly have a dependency on a another service.  Or have you tried a delayed start?

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me

```
protected override void OnAfterInstall(IDictionary savedState)
{
      base.OnAfterInstall(savedState);
      System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController sc = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController(serviceInstaller1.ServiceName);
      sc.Start();
}
```