# How can i start windows service automatically

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, windows-services

i try to develop a windows service. My win service must run if windows 7 stars up. How can i do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatically start a Windows Service on install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036713/automatically-start-a-windows-service-on-install)

Comment: Please ignore my vote to close - I had the wrong question link on the clipboard.

Answer (score 6):

Change the startup type of the service to `Automatic`.

You should create an installer application for your service (if you haven't already) and you can set this option in there so when its installed it is pre-configured this way. See [Walkthrough: Creating a Windows Service Application in the Component Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(VS.80).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Set the startup type to "Automatic".

Answer (score 0):

You set service startup to "Automatic" in service control manager. Not a programming question, by the way.

Comment: actually it is - installer programming.

Comment: @TomTom: Although the question has been *viewed* as an installer programming question, the OP doesn't actually mention anything about it which is why @Seva probably assumed he was referring to doing this via the service console.

Answer (score 0):

Actually make sure your installer sets the startup type on Automatic ;) Add dependencies as needed so that you start after dependent services.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set this programmatically (*i.e.* during the development phase) then this is set in the properties for the Installer (StartType), which you will also need.

Answer (score 0):

You could configure the service through the command line using the "SC" utility provided by Windows; it comes with XP and later.

> sc create MyServiceName binPath= <path
>   to service exe file> start= auto
>   DisplayName= MyServiceDisplayName
>
> sc description MyServiceName "This is
>   my service's description"

The spaces after arguments (like binPath= ) are important.