# How to auto start window service

Tags: c#, windows-services, visual-studio-2008-sp1, autostart

I have a window service which i developed in c# (vs2008).
please tell me what should i do to make it auto start after installation and also auto start on every time when system gets restarted.

EDIT:
I am using setup & deployment project to install it.
Thanks

Comment: How do you install your service?

Comment: @Albin: i am using setup & deployment project to install it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Follow the [instructions given here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddhy0byf(v=VS.90).aspx) to add an installer to your Service application.  Pay particular attention to step 5, where you set the [StartType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceinstaller.starttype(v=VS.90).aspx) property.

To start the service after installation, see [Automatically start a Windows Service on install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036713/automatically-start-a-windows-service-on-install)

Comment: #Jay: not able to find 'StartType' property. please tell me more about it

Comment: its for installer class, but i am using setup and deployment project.

Comment: @Rajesh: I edited.  You'll need to add an installer to your Service application - you can set use your Setup & Deployment project however.

Answer (score 2):

Try following way,

```
private void serviceInstaller_AfterInstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
        {
            var service = new ServiceController(serviceInstaller.ServiceName);
            if (service.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
            {
                service.Start();
            }
        }
```